# TabLayot не отображает значения во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Использую `TabLayout` во фрагменте, самы табы работают, но не отображает изображения(так же проверял текста).

xml фрагмента

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
```

Использую

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    setupTabIcons();




 private void setupTabIcons() {
        int[] tabIcons = {
                R.drawable.pers,
                R.drawable.clani,
                R.drawable.sssr,
                R.drawable.sssr,
                R.drawable.sssr
        };

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);
    }
```

Итого получается, как видим по оранжевому цветы, табы работают, но не отображает картинки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По оранжевому цвету мы видим, что табы уехали за пределы экрана - торчат только уши)) Вам нужно настроить их положение в разметке.

Comment: в том то и дело, что не уехали никуда. Я добавил скриншот, он выделяет его область. При нажатие. Аналогичную разметку я использую к активити, там всё отображается